# LWC refresh every time tab is clicked

Tags: lightning-web-components, refresh

I have a requirement that says "every" time a user clicks back to a tab that shows my LWC that it is updated. So this LWC is a custom listview. The user can click away from the LWC (NavigationMixin) and make changes that should change the listview. Currently, there has to be a page refresh.

I'm working on using Platform Events to update the listview LWC when relevant changes are made. I think this will work, but is there a better way? Anyone know how to trigger an update "every" time when the tab is clicked to return to the listview LWC. Something like a connectedCallback method that fires when the tab is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing this answer as per discussion in the comments section.

It is not directly possible to refresh LWC tab.
It can be achieved by wrapping LWC inside aura component as below :

1 Create a aura component which renders the desired LWC using `<aura:if>` and use it as the tab.

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome">
<aura:attribute name="isLwcVisible" type="Boolean" default="true"/>            
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.isLwcVisible}">         
   <c:myLwc />         
</aura:if> 
</aura:component>
```

2 For detecting navigation away from the tab , handle `aura:locationChange` event as below :

```
<aura:handler event="aura:locationChange" action="{!handleLocationChange}"/>
```

here , `handleLocationChange` will just toggle the property in `aura:if` which will cause the LWC to rerender.

```
({
    handleLocationChange: function(component, event, helper) {
        var isLwcVisible = component.get("v. isLwcVisible");
        if (isLwcVisible) {
            component.set("v. isLwcVisible", false);
        } else {
            component.set("v. isLwcVisible", true);
        }
    },
})
```

Special credits to @mackmama for this.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144338/discussion-on-answer-by-rohit-lwc-refresh-every-time-tab-is-clicked); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.